# Theme Mobile Padding Issue

Tags: css, wordpress

I have an issue with 100px padding on mobile

[Screenshot of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBL7P.png)

I've tried the following code but it's not working

```
.vc_custom_1521831418432 { padding-left: 15px !important; padding-right: 15px !important; }
```

Comment: where you added your css rule? and why is it not working( not overriding the default one, not visible in the console and etc. ). it's hard to debug code from screenshot. add html and related css-es into code snippet

Comment: Added in WordPress > Customise > additional CSS. It's not overriding the default code. This is the page that's having issues: https://wetndrysup.com/sup-locations/sup-lake/ I've also tried it with the caching plugins disabled

Comment: The fact that the default code is using important tags here should certainly be of concern to you.

Comment: why not to just change it from VisualComposer builder settings( on your page edit )?

Answer (score 0):

It will not override the css from file. You have to change padding from admin section.Please edit row or column of that page section from admin and you can change padding from 'Design option' of your page builder

Answer (score 0):

Your issue here is visual composer. No matter what you do on the CSS side of things, since visual composer applies !important to every rule which is applied in the back-end of that page, no matter what you do programatically, you will NOT be able to overwrite these rules.

Here's the documentation related link to how to work with padding, margins, and borders within visual composer: https://visualcomposer.io/docs/design-options/paddings-margins-borders-radius/

The padding has been applied to the parent row which is holding the columns, so be sure to go to the design tab within the admin back-end of that page, and set the padding to a value you want. Hope this helps! Good luck!